Non-tinted image in complications using WidgetKit
I have a watchOS app where a user can select a picture. I’d like the picture to be displayed in a complication.
I’m using WidgetKit, and I found out that for some watch faces (rendering mode = accented), the image gets tinted. Instead of the picture, the user sees only a colored box.
It appears that using the old framework, ClockKit, it was possible to display an image that gets slightly colored with the tint color on tinted watch faces. I believe this is to ensure backward compatibility of old complications.
My question is: can I do the same using WidgetKit? I tried using the widgetAccentable() modifier, but it doesn’t work.
Here's the code.
I have a basic widget bundle
@main
struct TestWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
  var body: some Widget {
    TestCounterWidget()
  }
}

And a simple timeline entry
struct TestEntry: TimelineEntry {
  var date: Date
}

My timeline provider doesn't do much for now either.
struct TestTimelineProvider: TimelineProvider {

  typealias Entry = TestEntry

  func placeholder(in context: Context) -> TestEntry {
    TestEntry(date: .now)
  }

  func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (TestEntry) -> Void) {
    let entry = TestEntry(date: .now)
    completion(entry)
  }

  func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<TestEntry>) -> Void) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentDate = Date()
    let entries = [TestEntry(date: .now)]
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(currentDate))
    completion(timeline)
  }
}

and finally the widget
struct TestCounterWidget: Widget {
  let kind: String = "TestCounterWidget"

  var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: TestTimelineProvider()) { entry in
      if #available(watchOS 10.0, *) {
        TestEntryView(entry: entry)
          .containerBackground(.black, for: .widget)
      } else {
        TestEntryView(entry: entry)
          .padding()
          .background(.black)
      }
    }
    .supportedFamilies([.accessoryRectangular])
    .configurationDisplayName("Title")
    .description("Description")
  }
}

struct TestEntryView: View {
  let entry: TestTimelineProvider.Entry

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      VStack {
        Group {
          Text("title")
            .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .medium))
            .foregroundStyle(.brandMain)
          Text("subtitle")
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium))
            .widgetAccentable()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      }
      Image("placeholder") 
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
        .widgetAccentable() // commenting this line shows a gray box, instead of a pink one on tinted watch faces.
    }
  }
}

The image placeholder is in the bundle and it's only 5kb. Here's the result:
A tinted watch face vs a non-tinted one.


Assuming you're using iOS 18 or watchOS 11, use                 .widgetAccentedRenderingMode(.desaturated)
